# The use of gender-specific pronouns on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, gender, inclusivity, pronouns

This is just a small lingual question, but it started bothering me when writing an answer. I was writing something like this: "As User1234 pointed out in his answer..."

Then I realized that if User1234 is a female user, she might be offended for a reason. Then I tried the same with "her". It did not feel very good, as the probability of her being him after all is quite high.

I ended up with "its". It is grammatically wrong and offends both genders and grammatically oriented readers. (Unless User1234 happens to be a machine which has passed the Turing test.)

So, what should I do?

- use him
- use her
- random.choice(['his', 'her'])
- use its
- use their (as PeterJ pointed out in their comment below)
- use his/her (as S.L. Barth pointed out in his/her comment below)
- go Spivak or something equvalent (e.g. eir, zhers, zer, zir)
- forget about giving anyone any credit
- bend my tongue double and invent creative phrases to avoid situations like this

I am not asking this tongue-in-cheek, even though some of the alternatives may look a bit funny. English is not my mother tongue, and thus I cannot rely on how it feels. What would be the best solution in order to avoid offending anyone (or sounding too funny)?

---

**Edit: A brief summary**

It seems that there is no single correct answer due to the nature of the language. Also, it seems that I am not the only one struggling with this issue even at SO. The following solutions are widely used:

- *singular they*: Native speakers find it "easy to read" in many cases, truly gender neutral, used for a long time (and can probably be found in Shakespeare's works...). Some claim it to be grammatically incorrect, but it is making its way into more formal use of English. Singular they cannot be used as a 1:1 replacement for he/she, e.g. "Pat took their book." != "Pat took her book".
- *he*: Has some tradition of being used as the gender neutral term, easy-to-use. Not really gender neutral in practice (i.e. may also indicate ignoring the problem instead of solving it). At SO the use of "him" will usually be correct in the strict sense ("male unless otherwise proven") but may be harmful because it may strenghten the prevailing stereotypes.
- dodging: If you cannot solve it, avoid it. This solution requires some extra thinking case-by-case and may require very good command of the language to avoid changing the meaning or producing unnecessarily complicated sentences.

By the votes it seems that I will start using singular they where applicable.

An additional question: Is there any difference between American, Canadian, English, Irish, Scottish, Indian, South-African, Australian, or New Zealand English? Or is this a geographically-neutral solution?

Comment: Personally I'd normally go with  "As User1234 pointed out in their answer..."

Comment: I usually use "(s)he" and "his/her".

Comment: I think that the use of "their" would be the most natural - it would "read" better than any of the alternatives.

Comment: While technically not grammatically correct, using the plural "their" as @PeterJ suggested is quite common in colloquial English, so that is always a safe option.

Comment: Somewhat related - [Does the SO community view itself as gender neutral?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222024/does-the-so-community-view-itself-as-gender-neutral)

Comment: Gender neutral is using plural forms; *The OP points out in their answer*. *You may want to tell the OP that they should do ...*.

Comment: See [Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun (“his” versus “her” versus “their”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) on english.se

Comment: "It" to refer to a person is almost never correct.

Comment: @unit 3524344: I know that. And yet at the same time it is the only singular gender-neutral pronoun in wide use I know of. It is also neutral in the sense that everyone should feel equally offended by its use...

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/generic-singular-pronouns?page=all

Comment: Use what you feel comfortable with..

Comment: It's funny that this is pretty much a problem of the anonymous Internet era, where you often can't easily determine the gender of the person with whom you are interacting with.

Comment: It can also be a problem IRL, @Cupcake. Hippies, man...

Comment: @staticx: I understand your point, but I really want to be a good member of this little community. That is why I want to be polite or at least non-offensive when choosing my words.

Comment: @Shog9 and boy, is it so ever embarrassing and awkward when you get it wrong!

Comment: I believe "he" is the gender-non-specific pronoun in English.  "She" is feminine, "it" is neuter, and "they" us plural.

Comment: Either 'their' or dodge: "As was pointed out in User1234's answer"

Comment: @bdimag: Somehow I get a different feeling from the passive form "As was pointed out" and the active sentence "Xxx pointed out", which seems to give more credit to Xxx. (This reminds me of my history teacher: "Do not use passive sentences when the actor is known!")

Comment: I'm content with the use of `it` and `its`. Anyone without a very clear gender indication in the form of a known gendered name or avatar looks pretty much genderless to me.

Comment: I would use:   "As pointed out in User1234's answer ...".  I also will use "s/he" when a subject pronoun is relevant.  Of course, as a native speaker of English, I can figure out games to play with the language, which is unfair to others.  And as a male who thinks he is sensitive, I'm not sure if I am more or less sensitive than females, who are more affected by the presumption of male-ness on Stack Overflow (but gender stereotyping does affect males as well).

Comment: At the risk of being redundant: “they” is a really good choice. “It” is correctish but sounds awful in the wrong context.

Comment: @false "it" never sounds right when referring to a person, *in any context* `:/`

Comment: @Cupcake: Who is it that gave you such an idea?

Comment: @false clever `:/`

Comment: Agreed use their... it's gender neutral. As a girl always being reffered to as he / him does get old fast however their works fine.

Comment: @TaiHirabayashi I actually knew a boy back in middle school who's first name was Tai, so I guess it's a gender neutral name?

Comment: @Cupcake Oh actually Tai for me is shortened from Tai-Lan (Chinese) but yes Tai in Chinese depending on the characters is a girls name. It depends on the language. In english however I think it's generally a boys name. The idea however for me at least is the assumption that everyone is male. Perhaps someday it will no longer be true :(

Comment: The pronoun game comes to SO!

Comment: Their is perfectly grammatical and has been for centuries! Declaring 'their' to be incorrect is a modern misunderstanding!

Comment: Perhaps `As User1234 pointed out in the answer...`?

Comment: I'm wondering whether we can just invent a SO language such as "As User1234 pointed out in `User1234.answer()`..."

Comment: Under any circumstance, avoid **Spivak**.

Comment: @DrV In Canada, we also use the singular "they". It's well received and commonly used.

Comment: @Cupcake: I find "it" is often used as a term of endearment when referring to one's own children (especially little ones). For example we regularly discuss "big it" and "little it"

Comment: @JeromyFrench Dang, you beat me to it.  I'm surprised you didn't have any upvotes on your comment...  To everyone else, the [pronoun game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun_game) refers to how LGBT people have done _exactly what his post talks about_ for years/decades to hide the gender of their significant other, when not out to everyone

Comment: Reminds me of the [node.js scandal](http://www.joyent.com/blog/the-power-of-a-pronoun).

Comment: I think this discussion is offensive for those men, women, ethnic groups that **actually had to fight for their freedom**

Comment: Use "their" because, contrary to popular belief, it has been a perfectly reasonable pronoun to use in this situation since the English language began. It was only when latin-biased grammarians started trying to "fix" English that it became evil.

Comment: For me: his/her = `their`, he/she = `s/he` or `they`

Comment: If the user didn't bother creating a gender-specific profile, then presumably he or she doesn't care about gender-correct pronouns.

Comment: I am a male and I always use "her" to counterbalance the ongoing disparity of the wrong usage of "his". I don't see any offence against the male dominated world in doing this.

Comment: @Cristian, thanks for the link. One needs a good cup of tea or two to read through that bunfight!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, Spivak pronouns are good too.

Comment: random.choice('his','her') is where i died XD

Comment: As a native English speaker, using "they" or "their" as singular is confusing and sounds awkward.

Comment: Why not simply use "you" when adressing OP?

Comment: New FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/476162

Comment: When addressing to a specific user, I generally use **he/she, his/her, him/her**.

Answer (score 299):

As I indicated in a comment on another answer, I think this does matter.

At 65, 44 years after I committed to programming as a career, and about 47 years after I wrote my first programs, nobody is going to put me off computer science by referring to me as a man. Also, at my age, I can afford to openly use a presumably-female given name on technical fora without attracting inappropriate e-mails.

I am much more concerned about some teenager who enjoys programming but is already coping with male-dominated robotics and programming clubs at school. Everything we can do to let her know that women are welcome in the programming community is worth doing.

There are a couple of a simple solutions.

In the specific context of referring to the person who asked a question on SO or who started a thread on USENET, I treat "OP" as though it were a pronoun.

That does not help with referring to someone who posted an answer or comment. When it would be awkward to avoid a pronoun I use "they", "them", and "their".

The English language survived, during a period that produced some of its enduring masterworks, the shift of a plural pronoun set to general singular use for reasons of politeness. See, for example, [Politeness in Early Modern English: the second person pronouns](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~eng121-c/politenessin%20AME.htm).

I think in modern English, with social conditions that include needing to refer to people in gender-neutral roles without face-to-face contact, making a similar shift in the third person pronoun is an entirely appropriate form of politeness.

Comment: +1 - Awesome answer in that it incorporates an individual's perspective through two lenses (senior and new), AND has a specific, viable suggested approach.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once. I'm getting gradually more annoyed by the people who think "Emily" is a male given name, to the point that I'm about to start referring to every one as "she" until proven otherwise *pouts*.

Comment: @Emily L. It is not very fair to assume that we English-as-umpteenth-language people would recognize the gender by the first name! How about Milan, Lennan, Charlie, Emory, Rowan or Jaylie? Or "Carl Maria"? Li? Jin? So please forgive us. Maybe there could this "bad English" sign in our profile so that we would be forgiven our ignorance :)

Comment: @DrV Well if you're not sure, go gender less. They, them, their, OP, the author, the user, the developer, one, etc. There are countless alternative ways to formulate sentences where one does not use specific gender pronouns.

Comment: @DrV I would go a step further than Emily. Don't even waste your time trying to guess. Just go genderless in an environment where gender is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Emily, Patricia: Yes, that is my approach. That is exactly why I was asking the question (as the OP) in the first place! And now I know that however ungrammatical it sounds, they is the way.

Comment: Hurrah for not-so-common sense. My own policy is clarity first, grammar second and political correctness a distant third. An examination of my works would no doubt reveal innumerable departures from this policy, but that's what I do when I give it thought. I do like OP as a new pronoun, since it greatly improves my chances of satisfying all three constraints. Capitalisation mandatory, since "op" is short for "operator".

Comment: As a matter of interest, "man" *is* gender neutral - http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=man - and English *does* have a gender neutral pronoun for objects: "it". What we *don't* have is a gender neutral pronoun that refers to a subject, and using an object pronoun for a person is both confusing and insulting. "OP" might well fill that void. Now that I think about it, op[erator] also works well here. Maybe we should all switch to lower case and also start pushing it in the rest of the world.

Comment: @PeterWone: Sure, *it* is grammatically gender-neutral, but it also only refers to inanimate objects, with only a few, specific exceptions (e.g. "Who is it?"). To anyone who is still unsure: Writers, dictionary editors, and other experts *of the English language* have already established that *they* and *their* are **absolutely correct and perfectly acceptable** to use as singular pronouns of indefinite gender, *even in formal writing*. It's even in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary entry for *they*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/they) if you need to see it for yourself.

Comment: I'd also like to underscore the earlier-linked [English Language & Usage question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) from the comments to the main question.

Comment: Noah Webster summarily decided to change several fundamental patterns of spelling and grammar simply to spite the English, and possession of a printing press does *not* make one an expert in anything.

Comment: @Peter Wone: OP is a handy pronoun in some situations, but it does not solve the original problem. "OP" can always be replaced by the nick of the original poster ("as OP said"/"as User1234 said") and v.v., but "OP took OP's book" does not sound very good. The question is how to replace "his/her/him/her".

Comment: Something I try to remember is *"Your/their code.."* to *"The code.."* given I am often prefixing analysis or critique of code (where the code clearly originates from some Q or A).  It's important (for me) to remember I'm critiquing code, not a person.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I agree that with code the criticism is about the code not the person producing it. However, sometimes the meaning is to emphasize the person: "User1234 shows in her excellent answer" vs. "As is shown in User1234's excellent answer" vs. "As is shown in the excellent answer #12837425."

Comment: Nice, see your point. I like to use the female pronoun when unsure, sometimes I will just toggle. However, in the end it is common practice in all languages I know of that the so-called male form is also used in a neutral way meaning both sexes. You don't even say she-doctor in English, something you can in German ("die Ärztin"). So to be honest, even girls new in our field should be used to it and not be offended. My oldest kid couldn't care less - and yep, she's a female soon-to-be-computer-scientist.

Comment: I'd rather offend my English teacher than either gender.  I'm glad to see use of the indefinite plural pronouns is gaining ground.  I'm confused by people using 'she' when gender is unknown as if it were somehow better than using 'he' - as if it didn't violate the same principle (sexism in the name of avoiding sexism).  Who knows - maybe the language 'officials' will eventually recognize the plural pronouns as having numeric meaning based on context (or no numeric specificity at all).

Comment: @PeterWone: _man_ is not gender neutral. See, IE languages have been shifting from a 2-gender animate/inanimate system to a 3-gender male/female/neuter system for the last millenia. As part of that, _man_ has taken male gender, _woman_ has become the female counterpart, and _human_ the neuter counterpart.

Comment: using a female pronoun is not a good option though as you are still potentially misgendering someone. If you don't know what pronouns someone prefers and yet must refer to them they/them/their is the best option because of gender neutrality.

Comment: @Peter Wone And possession of an opinion on the internet does not make one an expert in anything either. I'll take the dictionary's definition any day, over an opinion without a source.

Comment: @jinglesthula: I think the occasional fashion for referring to an example individual as 'she' is intended to redress existing gender imbalance. It is often used with roles traditionally assumed to be exclusively male. Whilst the intention is to reduce the assumption that the 'computer programmer' (or whatever) is male, I can see how it might be seen as sexist also! Reverting historic discriminations is a tricky business.

Comment: @Emily, 'possession of an opinion on the internet' - indeed! That made me giggle.

Comment: @halfer that lines up with what I've heard said about the reason for using 'she' in indefinite situations (redress or to increase awareness of problems that arise when using 'he').  Something is just waving a red flag in the back of my mind though.  It strikes me as a '2 wrongs don't make a right' situation.  Additionally, even if no one's feelings were involved it still has equal potential for confusion: to say 'she' implies gender is known, just as 'he' does.  I find it especially confusing/distracting when a person randomly trades off between the 2, detracting from clarity in communicating.

Comment: @halfer totally agree on reverting historic discriminations.  The pendulum can have momentum and overshoot (or veer off course).

Comment: I *strongly* dislike stylisticly the use of "they/their" as a singular, gender-neutral pronoun, even if I recognize the argument of its historical legitimacy.  I do like the OP's suggestion of using "OP" as a pronoun wherever it makes sense.  However, I think it's worth pointing out that it seemed to me all throughout my years in university that it was well accepted in computer science circles to use "she" as a gender-neutral pronoun (Alice really made the rounds in my classes...).

Comment: @SList When I got my first programming job, in 1970, the field was fairly evenly mixed between men and women. At that time, one could wait until adulthood to choose programming. Now, the intake is mainly with CS degrees, and to get a CS bachelor's degree requires a choice as a teenager. I don't know whether I would have been put off, as a teenager, by the current ratio or not.

Comment: I had the chance to write code at school, so I knew that it was fun and logical, years before I actually took it up as a career.  I think that's far more important in finding the right people to be programmers - give them the chance to write code while they're still at school, so that they can be exposed to the coding bug.  But still, it is important to respect that maybe more men than women will choose coding.  Or even women than men in the future.  Coding is very different today from how it was in 1970, and will evolve further.

Comment: @EmilyL - you will find that I did in fact provide a source, because I knew that someone like you would make a comment like that. Also, dictionaries are descriptive, not prescriptive. 200 million people passionately avowing that 2 + 2 = 5 does not make it so. As to the value of citations, I've often wondered why people feel that second-hand information is somehow superior.

Comment: @John Y and all the people who up-voted his comment - my original comment already states that "it" is an object pronoun and unsuitable for reference to people, why did you feel a need to tell me this?

Comment: @ninjalj - that is interesting and possibly true. But surely widespread printing slows this?

Comment: @SList - I heartily agree with your observation about the absence of a vast pool of discouraged candidates. It is obvious to me that for their own inexplicable reasons girls just aren't interested. I've often wondered why. It's indoor work with no heavy lifting, and the few female programmers I've known were much more talented than your run of the mill male programmer. A politically incorrect question worth contemplating: Why is this a problem? In what way would the world be a better place if we did somehow coax more women into the industry? (And don't say dating options!)

Comment: @PeterWone: I can't view the edit history of your comment, so I can't provide any proof; but I could have sworn that while I was writing my comment, yours made no mention of the limitations of *it*. Regardless of whether you added that part later, or I simply misread you, that is why I felt the need to respond as I did. As for the comment upvoters, maybe they were just expressing approval for the rest of my comment, and not anything to do with "refuting" you.

Comment: @PeterWone If you would like to satisfy your curiosity about why "girls just aren't interested" I suggest reading some of the extensive academic literature on the subject. [Google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22computer+programming%22+gender+imbalance&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) might be a good starting point:

Comment: @PeterWone You have not provided a source for the statement that they and their are not valid singular pronouns. Also it is not only merriam-webster but also Oxford dictionary,http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/they?q=They. Do the English spite the English too?

Comment: @Emily, the fact that "they" and "their" are plural is the first and most prominent fact in the Oxford dictionary entry that you cite. The entry goes on to document common usage patterns, but widespread abuse does not make the word singular, and the etymology is strictly plural. Adoption of idiomatic fads is a very common way to beg for group acceptance. I think this shows a weakness of character, which is why I refuse to bend to your will. I am therefore part of a minority group, so your own politics requires you to treat my every rabid utterance as sacrosanct.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - There's rather a lot of material on Google Scholar under "gender bias" which is what I just tried. Can you suggest a more targeted search term?

Comment: @JohnY - I did make several revisions in rapid succession. Going by the timestamps it's quite possible what we have here is a transactional problem, in which case I suppose I just have to take it on the chin and edit the first draft with more care.

Comment: @PeterWone Already done. Try clicking the link in my comment, repeated here for convenience: [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22computer+programming%22+gender+imbalance&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=)

Comment: @PeterWone let me try again: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/he-or-she-versus-they in case it's not "prominent" enough for you, here's a quote: "Some people object to the use of plural pronouns in this type of situation on the grounds that it’s ungrammatical. In fact, the use of plural pronouns to refer back to a singular subject isn’t new: it represents a revival of a practice dating from the 16th century. It’s increasingly common in current English and is now widely accepted both in speech and in writing."

Comment: @PeterWone Dost thou consider the speakers and writers of early modern English to have shown weakness of character when they chose to use "you" etc. as singular for reasons of politeness?

Comment: @PeterWone: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular-they http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf

Comment: @PeterWone The OED has sense #2 of *they* being for a singular entity of unknown or unspecified gender. That should put an end to this once and for all. It is not “wrong”.  It is normal and fine. You cannot expect anyone to take you seriously if you choose to stick your fingers in your ears and ignore seven centuries of actual, legitimate English use, including by its very best writers.  It’s a pointless battle you would wage, and no good can come of it.

Comment: @BenCollins If an unknown pregnant woman shows up, then she can get her own gendered pronoun. But if an unknown person of unspecified gender shows up, you cannot call them “she”, because now they have a gender, and that is not going to work.

Comment: @tcrist fair enough.  What I had in mind was in writing in the third person about an unknown or hypothetical subject.  Clearly, using 'she' generally doesn't work in interpersonal communication in which the subjects are known but their genders aren't. I think I have finally come to the place where I agree with the OP: 'When it would be awkward to avoid a pronoun I use "they", "them", and "their".'

Comment: FYI your “Politeness in Early Modern English: the second person pronouns” link is a 404

Answer (score 38):

[Patricia already pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262129/456814) a "new pronoun" uniquely available to us modern users of Internet media such as forums and Q&A sites:

> In the specific context of referring to the person who asked a question on SO or who started a thread on USENET, I treat "OP" as though it were a pronoun.

You could also expand "OP" to "original poster" for users who don't yet understand what "OP" means, though "OP" is understandably much easier to type.

### Additional "Stack Overflow" Pronouns

To add to the list of pronouns available to Stack Overflow users, I find myself occasionally using the following:

1. "**Asker**" to refer to the person who asked the question.
2. "**Answerer**" to refer to a person who posted an answer (usually I'm commenting on this person's answer, so there is no ambiguity with other answerers).

Comment: Thank you for these! How about someone who commented on an answer or on a question? Does it change if the comment is for my answer/question or someone else's answer/question?

Comment: @DrV you could use "commenter", and it doesn't change no matter where a person made a comment, though of course if there is more than one person who commented, you'll have to provide some additional information to make it clear which person you are referring to.

Comment: @Payeli I would use "commenter". "Commentator" doesn't sound right unless you're talking about a profession. See also [Commentator vs. commenter](http://grammarist.com/usage/commentator-commenter/), [Difference between “commentor” and “commentator”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2350/10590), and [What do you call who writes comments? Commenter or commentator?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11397/10590).

Comment: Commentators are really only on topic on the Cooking Stack exchange, and even then only when compared to Greater Taters (aka Idaho Potatoes).

Comment: Frankly I don't know why these two terms aren't used more over "OP". We eschew the terms "thread" and "reply" and "TS" (thread starter), so why "OP" and not "asker", considering the term "OP", despite standing for "Original Poster", only being used here to refer to the owner of a question, and not the owner of an answer?

Comment: @BoltClock for some incomprehensible reason, my browser's spellchecker doesn't think "asker" and "answerer" are words.

Answer (score 37):

I am female, I don't deny my femininity in real life, but I am going to carry on using "he" because (a) 9/10 programmers are male so it is more likely to be accurate and (b) "he" has been used as a neutral pronoun for centuries anyway, so there is plenty of precedent for this being correct.

There is really no point in anyone getting concerned about a pronoun.  If you care about women's rights, do something about FGM or forced marriages.  If you care about women in engineering, go and spend your time visiting girls' schools to promote programming.  But don't try to change the meaning of the English language, or censor what others are allowed to say, to promote your vision of how things ought to be - that is dishonest (not that the OP is being dictatorial, but that is the direction in which these things usually go).

Please do not run away with the idea that all women are offended by "he" and everyone must therefore change how they speak.

Comment: I understand that some people don't agree with language modification - even knowing they are in service of well-intended and progressive social goals - but I've not heard it being called dishonest before. Would you expand on that? If people are determined to carry on using male pronouns, even at the cost of being misunderstood, no-one will stop them on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is not true that nobody will stop them on SO.  I can easily see a situation where dedicated believers edit out all references to "he" in favour of another term.  It is very easy to do, for anyone with more than 2K Points.

Comment: I disagree that "he" is gender neutral. I think, particularly for native speakers, "they/their/them" is more commonly used as a gender neutral. As I said in my post below, what do you assume if I say "Brian's spouse says he loves SO"? Which conclusion are you more likely to draw, that I don't know Brian's spouse's gender, or that Brian is married to a man?

Comment: This is not a good example, because you are speaking about a specific person, about which you have given some information.  "The user" or "the programmer" for example, is not a specific person, it is any user or programmer, and "he" is a perfectly acceptable gender-neutral pronoun in that case, with a long history of use.

Comment: Great answer, imo. SO is not the place to worry about what gender someone is. It's irrelevant. We want good Q/A. The user's details don't matter in that regard.

Comment: @SList Most of the time when people are using pronouns on this site they are referring to OP or another answerer/commenter, so it is a specific person.  Also, there is no reason to assume the speaker knows someone's spouse just because they know the person.  Maybe Brian is a work colleague and I am just passing on something I heard from him.

Comment: @Cerbrus I completely agree; that is why gender accommodating language is beneficial.  If someone calls me "he" in a post, I have to decide if I want to correct them, making gender an issue, or not, perpetuating the stereotype women don't code.  Using gender neutral language prevents forcing me to decide how feminist I am feeling when all I want to do is ask and answer questions about programming.

Comment: @Barker: "He" isn't _"perpetuating the stereotype women don't code"_. The user that wrote that doen't mean "that guy", he means "that user". Don't ___make___ it a gender issue. We're not forcing you to decide how feminist you are. It's up to you how feminist you are.

Comment: @Cerbrus, except the "he" does mean male to people.  [In the book chapter I referenced in my answer](http://www.stanford.edu/class/linguist156/Boroditsky_ea_2003.pdf) they showed, for example, that if you tell a native German speaker an apple is named "Patrick" they are more likely to remember it than if it is named "Patricia" because it is a male noun in German (and opposite for Spanish where it is female).  If calling something that you know as a fact is not a man by a male pronoun can make you think of it as a man, how would that not be true for someone who might actually be a man?

Comment: @Barker: Because that is not the intention of the user that says "He". That user isn't _assuming_ you're a guy. In this context, "he" _is_ gender-neutral.

Comment: @Barker, the word "he" has 2 meanings, one means a man, and the other means gender neutral.  Please understand, that we are here to talk about programming, not to try and change the language to suit some people's politics.

Comment: @Cerbrus and SList I understand that "he" *can* mean both, but I have cited research showing that isn't how it is interpreted subconsciously and the majority (though not all) of the women posting here (who are most affected) have indicated they dislike the use of "he".  ["They" is a valid and long established substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) and doesn't have those downsides.  I honestly am curious, why do you feel so strongly that "he" should be used?  You have criticized the use of "they" but you haven't made an argument *for* "he".

Comment: I'm not saying "He" ___should___ be used, I'm saying it ___doesn't matter___. Nobody thinks about the user's gender when writing a comment on here, because gender _is irrelevant on SO_. I can also link to a bunch of articles saying "He" is gender-neutral. But what's that gonna achieve? Do you realize trying to _enforce_ the usage of "gender neutral" terms is counter productive? If someone wants to use "they", go them. I'm not stopping them. But if someone doesn't care about the "proper" pronoun, and by extension, gender, don't go making a big deal out of it. That's it. It's really that simple.

Comment: @Cerbrus I am sorry, I seem to be upsetting you; that is not my intent.  I am honestly trying to understand your perspective.  I am not mad at people who use "he" particularly if they are unaware some find it objectionable.  I am not editing posts to change "he" to "they".  When I was a kid, I didn't know what "gay" meant and to me it was just a synonym for "bad" and I used it as such.  When someone informed me of its meaning and impact, I stopped doing so.  I don't see how this is different.  I am informing people of the impact and hoping they will care enough to change.

Comment: @Barker: Informing people is fine. But some users really go out of their way to correct someone, because they're being "discriminated". My point is that saying "he" isn't discrimination. For a majo, not nearly enough thought went into writing "he", to make it discrimination.

Comment: @Cerbrus I haven't seen the circumstance you are describing. Maybe it is a difference in the topics we frequent, or maybe it is a difference in definition of "going out of their way". Could you link so I know what you are talking about? As for the last point, something doesn't have to be intentional to make it potentially discriminatory. If all the entrances to a building only have stairs because someone wasn't thinking about the disabled, that doesn't mean someone in a wheelchair can magically get in. I don't blame people who don't know, but the point of posting is so they do and may change.

Comment: **You couldn't be more right!!!**

Answer (score 32):

I wouldn't say that it's difficult to avoid using gender-specific pronouns, but it does require conscious effort. Interestingly, I find that I write *better* when I'm consciously trying to avoid them than I would otherwise, most likely because I'm paying sentence structure and communicating my ideas an equal amount of attention.

Ask a writer when you should use 'who' or 'whom' and they'll tell you to come up with a sentence where it no longer matters. That's basically what I do when I hit a 'him' or 'her' wall that I want to avoid.

"Them", "They", "Their", "They're" are good to use when gender isn't known. If Sally is the subject of a sentence, then I'm not going to hesitate to use "she" or "her", because there's obviously no reason not to do so. I've also gotten in the habit of saying "folks" instead of "guys", and just being more observant of what comes out of my mouth (and fingertips) in general.

With everything else, I'd *hope* that someone would be forgiving of me forgetting and trust that folks have the best intentions until they demonstrate otherwise; that I made the mistake *while trying to be helpful*. Don't agonize over it, but do make the effort. It's not just something you can do to make everyone feel more at-home here, honing your writing skills is never time wasted.

What counts is making the effort.

Comment: As long as Sally isn't short for Salvatore. When you guess someone's gender from their name you're normally right and occasionally wrong :-) You'd expect that a man named Sally will be used to it, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop My daughter is named Loren, not Lauren, that doesn't escape me at all ;)

Comment: What if it's Kelly rather than Sally?   "Kelly took their seat" seems very wrong; and if the gender is not known then rewriting the sentence to avoid the issue seems to be the only solution (e.g. "Kelly sat down").

Comment: You can always ask Sally what pronouns they prefer, then you don't have to worry about being wrong!

Comment: +1 - I didn't even know that you can use "they" etc. for this.

Answer (score 27):

I was the only female in a combined comp sci/math class, with math being the primary listing. This was not the first time I had been the only female in a class, but this class was taught by a female professor. One day our professor came in and said that another professor had asked her about how her "comp sci guys" were doing in this class. She went on to tell us how she had promptly corrected him stating that our class was in fact her "math guys". She went on to explain to the class that the only females that thrived in the programming world are those who assume a masculine demeanor and move as far away from their femininity as possible.

I was young at the time and though I found her assertion disconcerting, I did not challenge the statement. Thinking back now, I believe that it is extremely detrimental to female programmers for people, especially women, to perpetuate this type of thinking.

It is a fact that women are greatly outnumbered by men in this field and that most of the time the person that you are addressing will be a male. However, we women have a lot of ground to cover; do not take our gender away from us. I implore you to refrain from the use of 'his' if you are uncertain of the gender of the individual you are referring to.

It is because of the comments by this professor and the comments of so many others that I proudly display my femininity both in person and online. Many women choose a different path, by choosing either anonymity or masculinity. I applaud these women as well. The stereotypes and perceptions of women need to be broken down and we need as much diversity as possible to make this happen.

Comment: Agree with this. I tend to defend political correctness because people mostly forgot the original purpose of it: that language shapes culture and the way in which people think. Thus, making gender assumptions about CompSci undergrads, in a world that is sharply gender polarised already, might make the problem worse. I say "might" since I don't know of any proof of it, but it makes sense to me: how we speak reflects to others the way they believe we think. Thus, accidentally sexist assumptions reflected in speech may excuse or reinforce the ones that exist already.

Comment: On SO, you can expect to frequently encounter this. People generally assume I am male. Personally I don't take offense, because I use a neutral profile. However, if it's someone I recognize as an SO regular, I let them know. Most people are more than happy to change a "he" to a "she" once you tell them. And you always have the option to correct any post after 2K+ rep, else just leave a comment using '@'.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to avoid the gender issue in writing — and especially in technical writing — is not to use made-up pronouns (zer? really?) and not to torque existing pronouns into improper usage: it is to write in the plural voice. Instead of something like this, written in the 3rd person singular:

> A *developer* ought to take care that **his** code meets the agreed-upon coding standards.

Write in the 3rd person plural:

> *Developers* ought to take care that **their** code meets the agreed-upon coding standards.

One may write prescriptively without reference to gender as well:

> One ought to take care that one's code meets the agreed-upon coding standards.

Though to modern ears, it can sound somewhat stilted and overly formal.

Using your example,

> As User1234 pointed out in his answer...

Informal (conversational) usage generally accepts the singular use of the plural pronouns *they* (and the possesive *their*):

> As User1234 pointed out in their answer...

You could also avoid the reference to the author and say something like

> As was pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520312/467473) to the question, [cmd doesn't show all results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520290/cmd-doesnt-show-all-results)

One might also rewrite the sentence to avoid the pronoun altogether. Instead of something like this:

> If a developer wants to understand compiler design, he should read Aho & Ullman's most excellent "Dragon Book" (*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*).

Say

> A developer wanting to understand compiler design should read Aho & Ullman's most excellent "Dragon Book" (*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*).

It more declarative and straight to the point.

Comment: "Though to modern ears, it can sound somewhat stilted and overly formal." Try passive voice, and plainer prose: "Code should be written to meet the agreed-upon coding standard."

Answer (score 16):

As one of the women using the site, I would strongly prefer the use of "they" or "their" over any of the other options.  While strict grammatical rules say it is wrong, so is ending a sentence in a proposition, and people do that all the time.  It is colloquially common and removes all emphasis on gender.  It is the same reason why I use my last name as my SO name: it keeps it professional in case I want to reference my account on a résumé, but it doesn't inform people of my gender.  It is nice to be able to interact just as a programmer, not a female programmer.  That doesn't mean that I don't care about my gender or I am equally okay being thought of as a man, it means I don't want my gender to be thought of at all since it isn't relevant here.  Here are my reasons for objection to the other options:

1. **he** : While technically by the grammar rules no one uses, this is gender neutral, practically it isn't.  If I say "Brian's spouse says he loves SO."  You don't assume I don't know Brian's spouse's gender (even though I used the gender ambiguous "spouse" rather than "husband" or "wife"), you assume Brian is gay.
2. **she** : This feels too much like it is trying to make a statement.  It carries an implied gender, just like he, but since it is the opposite of the norm, it just feels like you are trying to point out "see, here's how it feels".  While I think it is good to discuss gender issue in the proper forum (that is why I made this post), it doesn't need to be injected into code debugging discussions.
3. **`random.choice(['he', 'she'])`** : If you keep it consistent in the post, it will cause one of the two previous problems.  If you change within a post it will be very confusing.
4. **it** : This pronoun isn't gender neutral, it is genderless.  It is used to refer to an object without a gender, and while some people may feel that is appropriate for them, the majority of people do identify with a gender.  It seems to take the approach of "I'd rather be wrong for (almost) everybody than only right for some".
5. **he/she** : While this is much better in terms of gender neutrality, and I would consider this the second most reasonable, it still makes gender a focus.  It implies importance on the gender of the person in question by making sure both options are available.  It refers to the male/female programmer, and I would rather something that just refers to the programmer.
6. **Spivak** : If this were common, it might work, but it isn't so you just sound like a weirdo.
7. **forget giving credit / reword** : This can be an option, but since in my mind the goal is to make gender not a focus, this in some ways may also be the worst option since it forces the poster to labor over their language to avoid gender, making it more noticeable to them.  I would rather have something that you can use naturally and easily so that the gender of the people involved never crosses anyone's mind
   .

For an interesting read on how gender pronouns can effect the way we think (and part of why I think it can benefit us to not use them), I suggest this chapter on [Sex, Syntax, and Semantics](http://www.stanford.edu/class/linguist156/Boroditsky_ea_2003.pdf) in *Language in mind: Advances in the study of language and cognition*.  It discusses a number of studies involving how languages with genders for inanimate objects effect the minds of native speakers.  For instance, even when speaking English, native German speakers (where bridge is feminine) describe bridges as "beautiful, elegant, fragile, pretty, and slender" where as Spanish speakers (where it is masculine) consider them "big, dangerous, strong, sturdy, and towering".  Some of the studies include English as a control (since we don't assign genders to inanimate objects) meaning that the bias created by the gendered language disappears when the gender is removed.

I like that by using "they" my bridge will more likely be judged as "sturdy" or "beautiful" based on its quality, not on whether I decide to correct an in accurate "he".

Comment: Better idea: omit pronouns altogether.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is a worthwhile discussion that you've pushed back onto the front page!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but does this discussion really need to get pushed back onto the front page? There are a bazillion answers on here already.

Comment: @TinyGiant, that falls under the 7th option.  It works for the readers, but can be a lot of work for the writer, making them very aware they are doing this to avoid gender as they are writing.  I once submitted to a journal that allowed absolutely no active voice, and I have never been more aware of who was doing the action I was describing than when I had to avoid sentences stating it.

Comment: The other problem with avoiding pronouns (like avoiding active voice) is that it tends to make the sentences more wordy and therefore more difficult to understand. Aside from being tedious for the author to write this way, it is difficult for others to read—especially on an international website where many people do not speak English as their first language and therefore won't be familiar with more esoteric and cumbersome constructions. On another note, this is a beautifully written, incredibly perceptive, and 100% correct answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to write and post it.

Comment: *While strict grammatical rules say it is wrong* - Well that depends on who you ask. But I otherwise agree: I personally use they and OP on SE sites. Gender-specific pronouns are jarring to me and I can never be sure when someone else uses one if they actually know the other user's gender or if they're just making an assumption. And while I frequent a couple of sites that default to "she" and it works, SO actually has data that says ~90% of users are male.

Comment: I did not mean that you should reword things in such a way as to not need pronouns. I meant to write the sentences using whatever pronoun is natural, then go back and just remove those words.

Answer (score 13):

With a bit a practice it will become second nature to write text where one does not assume a gender.

Personally I prefer 
*them/their* as I find it rather polite to refer to some one in plural and it's gender neutral, win-win. If nothing else it shows consideration for not wanting to offend your readers, which is always a plus in my book.

Another way is to not refer to the gender your talking to but rather the person. I know it sounds a bit weird so please let me explain. For example right now I'm on SO discussing with people, developers, administrators, reviewers, humans, nerds, geeks, authors, artists, parents, children, etc. I'm not talking specifically to men or women, nor am I assuming the gender of any one who is reading.

As my closing statement I would like to to caution against using a blanket "him/his" for every one. Some may find that okay, while others may find it unfair. Some may feel offended. Consider how you would feel if some one consistently misgendered you with the opposite pronoun. Would you be fine by that, or would you get annoyed to be assumed to be of the opposite sex?

Comment: +1 for "Consider how you would feel if some one consistently misgendered you with the opposite pronoun". About 20 years ago, I read a computer book where the term "Die Userin" (German for a female user) was used everywhere, and I found it very irritating at the time.

Comment: I'm curious about what effect that had on you after you read the book? Apart from the obvious irritation, ofcourse.

Comment: I started thinking about the underlying problem - how would I feel if every book was written in this way? How would I feel if I was a woman and every book was talking about male users? So in a way, for me it raised the very same question we're discussing right here. But until now, I stuck to the male pronoun "he" on SO mainly because he/she, his/her etc. feels so awkward and I didn't know that you could use they/their as a neutral singular. I'll try to use this consistently in the future.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here. *You* takes plural verb concord but either singular or plural pronominal concord: *Jim, you eat it by yourself* compared with *Folks, you eat it by yourselves.*  No one would claim that the Jim case is plural, despite the plural verb; notice that the reflexive/intensive pronoun is *yourself* in the singular. The use of singular *they* works the very same way, and is no more plural than singular *you* is. “If someone gets here before me, they are welcome to eat it all by themself” in singular but “My friends, they can eat it all by themselves” in plural.

Comment: "About 20 years ago, I read a computer book where the term "Die Userin" (German for a female user) was used everywhere, and I found it very irritating at the time." - I would not find this irritating because of the gender identification, but I certainly would be irritated by the perception that the author had a political axe to grind.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the time, pronouns can be avoided in technical writing by not referring to the person but to the answer that the person provided.

Writing something like "I like his answer" or "I found her idea very innovative" works just as well as "I like this answer" or "I like the answer provided by User1234", and "I found the User1234's answer innovative" and so on.

After all, SO is not a critique on the people, but on the answers provided toward the best solution. I don't see how third-person personal pronouns are really all that important.

Answer (score 11):

I've come across this problem fairly frequently throughout my career. The following rules of thumb have worked well for me:

1. If you know for certain the gender of the person, then **use the appropriate pronouns**.
2. If it is easy to avoid the use of the pronouns without making the content harder to read, then **avoid using the gender specific pronouns entirely**.
3. If you are writing to a known audience that has a very strong English background, then **use he/him/his** since they are traditionally considered gender neutral and tend to make the content easier to read. This can be very subjective, since even people who have spoken English their entire lives don't realize that some people intend "he" to be gender neutral.
4. If you don't know your audience or your audience has varying cultural or language backgrounds, then **use "he or she," "his or hers," and "him or her"**.

I recommend never using the gender female words when the gender is unknown. From my experience it tends to distract some readers from the actual point you are trying to make (they start thinking about gender equality or whether or not using "her" is appropriate instead of thinking about whether the technical details make sense). This is very reader dependent though, so your experience may vary.

In the case where you do offend someone by using the wrong pronouns, sincerely apologize and make sure you always use the right pronouns for that person in the future.

Comment: Interesting points, but I'm not sure I agree with 'he/his/him' as gender neutral. They were originally, as with 'mankind', but I wonder if that fell out of fashion, and not really as a response to the PC movement. Now 'he' intended as a gender-neutral pronoun sounds rather dated to my ears.

Comment: In the meantime, where an example person is given a female gender ("Jane the racing driver", "Sophie the DBA") and this is found by a reader to be jarring, that might be subconscious sexism at play, and choosing that language deliberately is meant to chip away at that sexism. If it sounds odd to some people that Jane and Sophie work in male-dominated roles, that to me explains how society's filtering processes work on Janes and Sophies from a young age, accidentally discouraging careers in racing driving and database analysis.

Comment: Using "he or she" as a way to "catch all" is plain wrong at best and downright offensive at worst. Those 2 pronouns are not the most suitable (or even a remotely appropriate) way of addressing everyone in the world, especially in a language/culture-background agnostic setting. Certain intersex or transgender people (yes, we do exist, even in the programming world) would not take so kindly to you assuming that everyone is either male or female.

Comment: I agree with most of your post, but I, like @halfer, disagree that "he/his/him" is gender neutral.  I think, particularly for native speakers, "they/their/them" is more commonly used as a gender neutral.  As I said in my post below, what do you assume if I say "Brian's spouse says he loves SO"? Which conclusion are you more likely to draw, that I don't know Brian's spouse's gender, or that Brian is married to a man?

Answer (score 10):

When possible, I dodge the bullet:

> As User1234 pointed out in [this answer](link here)...

If I have to, I usually just assume "male unless proven otherwise" and use "him". If it's a female and she cares enough she will put a comment and I will happily change to "her".

Comment: I used not to worry about this, but given the shortage of girls feeding into the computer science education pipeline in the USA, I'm worried that "male unless proven otherwise" could put some kid off by making her feel that being a programmer is inherent male.

Comment: +1. If it's a question/answer I can always edit incorrect pronouns :) For the record, I don't take any offense to this.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan: I could not agree more with you, but would like to remind that there are other countries outside of the US, and that the situation is not necessarily that different in the countries where the dominant language does not have gender specific pronouns. LAnguage may play some role, but it is only a minor role. Programmer seems to be a young male with eyeglasses, poor interpersonal skills, and bad skin regardless of the cultural background...

Comment: Agreed with Patricia Shanahan. And I believe this sentiment "male until proven otherwise" is rather a saddening proof of the fact that men are (deliberately or not) still diminishing women and their contributions in many professions and fields. @DrV And that is a proper confirmation bias you're having there.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan While I do agree that we could use more strong, visible female role-models, I don't think SO is the right platform for it.  The focus should always be on the correct answer, not the person's gender or nationality.

Comment: @Emily L. I do not seriously mean to claim that programmers would be what I described in my comment. I know very well that the world is - fortunately - much more diverse. But everywhere I have been talking with laypeople the stereotype seems to be the same. I do not want to downplay the significance of proper use of language (hey, I started this discussion!), but I am afraid it is not the most important factor. There seem to be strong, global language-independent factors behind this dilemma.

Comment: @cimmanon: On the other hand, there would be some value in seeing that there are hard-core female nerds with the best answers, something like Jane Skeet. (Personally, I like the possibility of backgroundlessness offered by using nicknames and blank profiles. I want to be judged by what I say, not what I am.)

Comment: @EmilyL. I disagree that a heuristic based on the easily observable fact that men outnumber women in software fields is proof of anything other than that software engineers tend to think logically and have lower than average political correctness.

Comment: @EmilyL. "It is easy to find a stick to beat a dog with". This "male until proven otherwise" is pure (yet flawed, granted) logic on a site like this. If the statistics change and people would still hold on to this way of approaching things, then I would agree with you. Until that time, I'll use the slightly better "genderless until proven otherwise" and hope that we steer clear of calling out sexism where it isn't needed/helpful. You wouldn't call presuming people were born in America because they live in America racist or diminishing other countries contributions would you?

Comment: @SvenT23 Yeah, but this dog has gone and deserved it for the better part of my life :P I understand that my reaction to the "problem" may seem harsh to some one who is not, has never been, and will never be affected by said "problem". It's not just on SO it's literally everywhere. Sorry if I seem a bit rabid, but I really do feel quite strongly about this.

Comment: @EmilyL. I'm not saying the dog isn't an asshole either ;) I just think that there is no detrimental reasoning behind the problem, so it shouldn't be made part of a much larger issue ... there's a lot of unjust in this world that needs the attention way more than this kind of lazy addressing of a person you have no information about

Comment: On the topic of assuming male, consider that a user who has made the decision to hide her gender may not want to correct you if you use the wrong pronoun.

Answer (score 10):

In my humble opinion, since the answer-ers are spending their time and effort to help the OP solve the issue with no pay, if the gender is not apparent then the OP should not be offended by the misused "him" or "her".

People don't actually care if they are helped by a male or a female, a good answer is a good answer. As such, we shouldn't make much of either gender - male or female. This means that it truly doesn't matter if someone uses "her" or "him" incorrectly due to a lack of information.

If it truly matters to the ask-er or answer-er then they should make that apparent through their name.

Let's focus a little bit less on nit-picky English and focus a bit more on what SO is for - helping people with their code.

Comment: +100 for this. I understand the overtone, which is that if we can be genderless in our pronouns we should be. however to have a drawn out discussion about which is acceptable sounds like a time sink when there is code to be written!

Comment: I think that this is the very place that we should be discussing this issue. There are programmers all over the world on SO. This site touches many. This issue is more than just how we are referring to individuals, it is more about what type of environment we are creating for women in the future. It is imperative that more women become developers because the collaboration between people who think differently has amazing results. Choosing to stick with the status quo is not going to make things better.

Comment: I'm going with 'it' then. You are all 'its' until proven genderwise.

Comment: @rlemon or you can use 'human'. however, this has a similar issue in that you are assuming that you are not speaking with a non-humanoid being.

Comment: @Jenn If you can create a gender-neutral pronoun group and get it to spread ubiquitously through the English language, great. Until then, don't make a big deal out of something insignificant. Call me a girl until you know otherwise; I honestly don't mind, and neither will any other guy. Because it doesn't matter. It's not an insult. If people get put down about it then we should explain to them that it isn't a put-down, not call it a great injustice.

Comment: @TylerH - gender-based disparity of opportunity (at least as I understand it in mainstream Western culture) is not viewed by everyone as "something insignificant". How much of a connection one makes between language and that disparity is possibly not on topic for this forum, but the issue of equal opportunities for all genders has some way to go in several major spheres of life: remuneration, company control, political representation, and so forth. Thus, it's fine to disagree, but accommodating people's views in this area I think is a good thing.

Comment: @Zach: my answer above explains why I disagree that this issue isn't just about "nit-picky English". Language likely has an effect on how ideas are formed - and that includes gender role models. I agree with Patricia's point that encouraging more women into the field is a worthwhile ideal.

Comment: @TylerH I agree with you that misspeaking about a persons gender is not an insult, it is a mistake. However, that doesn't mean that we should ignore or avoid the topic. What I am suggesting is that we should not adopt the practice of assuming the person on the other side of the conversation is male. Frankly, that assumption does not open the door for women and it hinders the community as a whole.

Comment: @Jenn We must assume they are either male or female. So males by default tend to pick males and females by default tend to pick female when gender is otherwise unknown. This isn't a problem. If they get it right, great. If not, correct them if you are that concerned about it. Simple workflow. Until then, continue working to bring a gender-neutral pronoun group to fruition.

Comment: @TylerH Why do you need to make this assumption? As pointed out in other answers, there are so many other ways to address people here. Also, I would disagree with your assertion that "males... pick males and females... pick females" Is that based on personal experience or on data? It is not just myself trying to find a gender-neutral pronoun. That is the point of this post and several people have suggestion fantastic options. As a collective, we can make an effort to change and the people who read this question have the opportunity to effect change through their posts in the community.

Comment: @Jenn You need to make this assumption any time you want to refer to a person. My assertion is based on psychological profiles of male psyche vs female psyche. People project the world around them based on their own experience of reality(ie that of being male or female). As you've said, there are some options, but those are clunky and awkward at best, and not really applicable at worst (some [OP] aren't even usable outside of an internet context). As a collective we don't need to make an effort to change because there is not a good reason or need to change.

Comment: I could understand this feeling more if we weren't in a field with a lot of gender inequality, but we are.  If you want women to feel comfortable in the field, they need to not feel like outsiders.  Using gender accommodating language can help that happen.

Comment: @Barker: SO isn't a social networking site where we can buddy up and make people feel welcome. SO is about quality Q/A. A person's gender, race, sexual preference or hobbies are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Cerbrus I completely agree (though you caught my attention in the elections because we both like horses), that is actually the point.  None of those things should matter, and shouldn't even have to come up.  If you call everyone, "he" suddenly it does matter because if it is a woman, they have to decide if they want correct you (making gender relevant) or not (perpetuating the stereotype that women don't code).  I just want to ask and answer questions about coding, not consider how feminist I am feeling today, and using gender accommodating language lets me do that.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, in doubt, I use the female pronoun.

Not being a native speaker, the reason is not one of linguistic, but simply that given the choice between:

- using a male pronoun, and making our field a bit more grating for girls/women
- using a female pronoun, and having guys wondering why I would do that

I preferred the latter.

The underlying belief, of course, is that a man would not be offended by it, or would just brush it off as a quirk of language. It is imperfect, certainly, but in practice I was never called upon it so I would guess it works well.

It is also reactionary because in French the default gender is male; and this explains why I may sometimes slip up and use a male pronoun.

Comment: Wouldn't your rationale imply that women are more prone to take offense (inferring from the assumption that men wouldn't)? It sounds like a slight victimization of the gender. (Having said that, I do agree with you. Just pointing out a weakness in your/mine attitude. Please regard this comment as an amuzement.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I certainly hope that this is not how it comes across :) It is just that: 1. between the choice of offending either gender, I'd rather offend men (for once!) and 2. I believe that men are comfortably enough installed in the field that they are less likely to feel shunned, and thus take offense.

Comment: As I said - I do agree with you fully, including your latest remark. I feel it's important to point out (for other readers) that there are more significant differences in proneness to take offense between males (originating in different countries or brought from different socioeconomical households) then there are between males and females. It's my strong opinion that people are generally to prone to take offense nowadays. Let be that I might be a bit of buffalo myself, I still feel that way too many people make way too huge deal of way too insignificant details. (+1 in any case)

Comment: Focusing on either gender is counter productive to gender equality

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Well, opening doors to ladies is counter productive to gender equality as well, yet they generally appreciate the gesture :)

Comment: Opening doors is nice.  Using the female pronoun for someone who is 90% likely to be male, is an artificial construct and an offense against truth.  I don't like it (I am female).

Comment: @ZachSaucier As an end goal, sure. But sometimes when things are out of balance you need to push harder to get them to the middle. I don't think I'll switch to using 'she' myself, but I like the idea that Matthieu had put forward of using it as a reactionary measure to make users stop and think.

Comment: I used to try to "randomly" alternate male and female for generic pronouns. The problem is that the human brain doesn't do random very well. Whenever one of the generic people in a discourse is dumb, I found myself writing him as male without thinking, which is probably either insulting to males or patronizing to women (assuming they "can't take it"). So I no longer do that. I suspect using female universally would have the same feeling, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I am not a woman, nor do I believe for a moment that careless use of pronouns has any bearing on the *actual* marginalization of women in any way.  I prefer to believe that women are at least as perceptive as my insensitive self to the actual attitudes of their peers, and just maybe not so much more emotionally fragile than myself either.  Consequently, my answer is more concerned with practical use of grammar to communicate information rather than lacing a conversation with a subtext of distracting social commentary/grammatical strangeness, or on even exerting some effort not strictly in service of the former.

---

The French language has a similar issue with 'elle/elles', which are the 3rd-person singular/plural pronouns meaning a group that may contain women.  In the French example, the pronoun referencing women is 'diluted' with male presence, while the male pronoun ('il/ils') retains exclusivity.  This seems problematic to me because obviously men are being given special consideration/distinction, making elle/elles seem like a reference with lesser status - there's basically "man" or "person."  I believe the 2nd-person pronouns work the same.

In English, the situation is reversed, and I find it surprising we're not happy with that, as it gives the special consideration to women if indeed anyone.  Every day the vast majority of the western world uses the 3rd-person singular pronoun 'he' to refer to either a man or a person of unknown gender.  The same people only use the word 'she' when referring to a person known to be female.

It seems to me that 'he' already serves the purpose of a gender-neutral pronoun, and all that's needed is for our definition to catch up with our usage - and it somewhat already has:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/he

The real inequality is that we have a term that singles out a subject as female but *do not* have have a term which singles out a subject as male.  Our constant use of 'he' when referring to someone of unknown gender - over the past 30 years at least - clearly precludes the word from holding that position in any practical sense.  If the use of 'he' *could* be using the secondary definition, then we can't ever actually presume the primary definition was intended.

If there's really a problem with any pronoun, it is with 'she', and the solution is to simply discontinue its use.  Continue treating 'he' as gender-neutral, like we basically already do.  Indeed already many other such feminine-variant words are already falling out of use at least in some areas: actress, waitress, etc.  This abandonment of gender-specific terms seems like the natural linguistic progression for a society where gender is no longer relevant (or at least significant) in most contexts.  And, while the pronouns will likely be the last to truly disappear, they ought to be the first.

Comment: As an aside, one cannot possibly expect womankind as some kind of collective to decide whether (and when) they want the security of gender-neutral anonymity or to assume a publicly feminine identity.  But I'm perfectly happy to start with a reasonable guess and ajust according to an individual's stated identity/preference.  Only the abstract archetype has no voice in this approach - and he'll survive.

Comment: _"the vast majority of the western world uses the 3rd-person singular pronoun 'he' to refer to either a man or a person of unknown gender"_ - I don't think you'll garner widespread agreement there. Using gendered language such as chairman, he, man-hours has often been replaced with chairperson, he/she, person-hours (etc), and this shift in language has been going on (at least to my UK perception) for the last thirty years or so.

Comment: Your point about the swapping of 'actress' to 'actor' though is interesting - the Guardian Style Guide (from the UK-based newspaper of that name) specifically endorses that one. The reasoning behind it, I believe, is that it was felt (rightly or wrongly) 'actress' had developed patronising characteristics, and that parity could be found in 'actor'. But 'actor' isn't male-gendered in the same way as my earlier examples, so it doesn't suffer from the problem of prioritising male-gendered words over female-gendered ones.

Comment: _If there's really a problem with any pronoun, it is with 'she', and the solution is to simply discontinue its use_ - I disagree for the reasons set out above. More importantly, English doesn't seem to be going in this direction, so adhering to such a rule would make one sound increasingly archaic (provided that genderless pronouns remains the direction in which we are all (mostly) travelling).

Comment: I should apologize for casting my generalizations a little wide with "western world."  My experience is largely with North American cultures and includes Europe and the UK only thorugh popular media and a few meager contacts.  And in NA (especially Canada) there was a push for female-genered and then gender-neutral terms like you describe back in the nineties.  It basically failed and became the poster child for the perils of political correctness by fabricating frivolous controversy and offenses while no one could figure out what was supposed to be socially acceptable that day.

Comment: In the end, it just made people feel stupid for using made-up words and like the feminist movement had run out of real problems to solve. Today, someone who insists on being called chairwoman is accommodated with little thought because identifying with your gender is widely respected. In contrast, if you insisted on being called chairperson you'd be seen as socially combatitive and playing a weird breed of victim card - actually if you've seen the feminisim-first bookstore skits in the show Portlandia, that's an apt depiction - someone seeking out offenses over gender distinction or overlap.

Comment: No apology necessary! We may have to disagree on whether the modification of language promoted by PC was a good mechanism for changing embedded societal discrimination. But the problems on race/gender/sexuality that it was intended to fix persist to this day (though perhaps to a lesser degree, so it may have helped - perhaps not possible to say). However, it seems to be quite obvious that there is not equality of opportunity within the field of computing.

Comment: If we agree on that, and there is opposition to using an inclusive form of language, then how shall we correct this discrimination?

Comment: Well, I guess the gist of my whole position is that there's no real drawback to just gender-neutralizing the masculine forms, so the problem is fixing itself - the masculine forms are *becoming* the inclusive form.  Regardless of attempts to artificially manipulate social mores through language, the way we *perceive* language only reflects the real attitudes of the cultures consuming it.

Comment: Regarding the shortange of women in computer science specifically, the current problem seems not to be continuing discrimination but consistent lack of interest in the field. Hopefully - perhaps even probably - it's inertia from a history of discrimination. Around here at least this seems to be the concensus, and the resulting approach has been programs promoting and nurturing female interest from early youth and throughout grade school. The disparity of interest is far lower with the current generation of youth so that looks promising, but it'll take a decade to tell for sure.

Comment: What's really worrying is the attitudes of the women who *are* in CS. The vast majority of them seem to go into testing, and the ones I've spoken with don't want to program at all - even ones which I know would be brilliant at it. I'm not as concerned about women who find programming mind-numbingly dull (lets not forget most men do too after all), but few men go through CS aspiring to test other people's work. Either there are actual physiological factors at play governing their interests, or the current generation has still been raised with a predisposition against logic as an art-form.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe the latter, thus reinforcing the "get them while they're young" approach.  And ironically, the implication I'm making that programming is a higher calling than testing could be itself discrimination, which I'm applying only because *I* find testing mind-numbingly dull. The female tester on my team does a good job of justifying why it's interesting (rewarding?) for her.  I'm not sure whether the male tester actually likes his job or not.  Whatever the case, these real gender disparity issues are quite far removed from one's choice of pronoun in professional conversation.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. "the way we perceive language only reflects the real attitudes of the cultures consuming it". I agree, but my view is that the feedback loop works the other way too: our speech modifies culture. But I am glad to see you recognise a history of gender discrimination - I originally misunderstood your comments "the feminist movement had run out of real problems to solve" and "weird breed of victim" as intending to oppose equality of gender opportunity.

Comment: Your comparison with the French language is interesting, but I would draw opposite conclusions from it. Firstly, "une personne" (a person, obviously) is always a female noun, so if you use it to talk about someone, you can then refer to it as "elle", irrespectively of the gender of the individual. Secondly (regarding actress -> actor), the tendency over the past decade (or maybe a bit more) has been to feminise male nouns that represent a function ("lA professeurE", "l'auteurE", ...) when talking about a woman in that function (for a more gender-balanced political correctness). [...]

Comment: [...cont'd...] This would indicate that at least some French feminists (hard to treat feminist as a single category speaking with one voice) consider the lack of gender in nouns to be against their interests, and might disagree with "*This abandonment of gender-specific terms seems like the natural linguistic progression for a society where gender is no longer relevant*" (unless perhaps they don't want gender not to be relevant). This, put in the context of the opposite tendency that happens in English, would seem to suggest that neither are the solution when trying to prevent discrimination.

Comment: The one thing you can count on is people identifying with a cause and finding fault with whatever happens to be the norm.  Since there will never be a perfect way to magically deduce exactly what every individual wants and indivdual preferences often contradict each other - compund that with the common ability of the human imagination to arbitrarily invent cause-effect relationships (imaginary solutions to real problems) - and the collective grass will always be greener on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

### Writing without singular third-person pronouns is not difficult and should typically be expected on Stack Overflow

It's a little absurd to me that any option besides "omit pronouns altogether" is being considered. It's highly absurd to me that any option at all is being thought of as even potentially *offensive*; but in my experience, avoiding third-person singular pronouns consistently results in clearer, more effective technical writing.

As my name suggests, I am a man. However, in some places online, I use an avatar that causes some to identify me mistakenly as female, even if my username ought (IMO) to serve as countering evidence. (It's a long story, but suffice to say that my choice of avatar does not reflect any lack of confidence in my gender identity.)

When others err in this regard, I have never taken any offense at this. Sometimes it takes me a little while to recall what my avatar looks like, and then it's just amusing. I make a polite explanation and get on with my day. I can't recall seeing anyone persist in such behaviour past that point; but I know quite well that I would just ignore it. I've said it elsewhere many times and I'll say it again here: if other people wrongly perceive me as a woman, that is their problem, not mine; they are entitled to disagree with me, they are entitled to their respective opinions, and they are entitled to be factually incorrect (supposing *arguendo* that gender were an objective matter).

I have told people in the past that "my pronouns are you/you". Referring to me in third person when I am present is something I consider inherently impolite. Referring to me in third person behind my back is something I don't care about, since again it is a matter of someone else's perception of me, not of my essential nature.

I avoid "singular they" in my writing, and even in casual speech. It's not difficult, with practice. **I have found that activists are generally prevaricating** when they discuss the concept. While it's certainly true that the use of "singular they" has a long history of use in English, opinion about its correctness has varied over time. More importantly, historical evidence *only* supports the such use to refer to an *unknown or generic individual* - that is, as a casual synonym for the formal third-person pronoun "one". It does not, as far as I've been shown at least, support such use for a definite individual of unknown gender. On the other hand, I have seen many people make the argument while completely glossing over that crucial distinction.

"Singular they" often causes confusion over whether the subject is intended to be singular or plural, *even in the simplest cases*. I can easily recall the feeling of confusion caused by well-meaning younger friends saying "they" to refer to an individual whose gender was already established. English readers and listeners rely on both grammatical gender and grammatical number as a context clue for disambiguating the referent of third-person pronouns. It gets worse as soon as there's any call for noun-verb agreement on grammatical number; and I have not seen agreement on the reflexive form (should it be "themself" or "themselves"?).

But aside from that, **there is no good reason for third-person pronouns in general** on Stack Overflow:

- Credit to others needs to *name* the person credited ("We can solve the foo problem with code like so, as described by So-and-so [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)); beyond that point, there is no need to refer to that person again.
- Reference to other answers is usually a bad idea, except perhaps on Meta; but even then, once the answer has been identified (by its author's name), the rest of the prose should discuss **the content, not the author** - so there is no need for a pronoun.
- Reference to other users, in comments, is **rarely needed at all** - really, only in comments *that should be promptly deleted anyway* as "no longer necessary". Pointing at specific users is a good way to provoke heated discussion; comments on Stack Overflow are intended to be about neither heat nor discussion.

For that matter, **I also avoid "you"** in Stack Overflow answers, because I don't want the OP to feel singled out, nor do I want future readers to feel excluded or set aside. I have found that imperative (but polite) tone works better for guiding others through a process, anyway.

---

The attentive reader will notice that I have not used "singular they" in this answer. (I do, of course, use "plural they"; I obviously don't find that objectionable.) It generally takes me no effort to ensure this, as the idea of using it simply doesn't enter my mind (indeed, I had no such hiccups with this answer). On rare occasions, I need to think a little bit; I have consistently found that this effort improves my prose.

If you spot any unnecessary use of pronouns in my old answers, feel free to let me know. I have not always been as disciplined as I am now; my current stance is largely a response to being forced to think about these issues - well, around the time this Meta question was originally posted. I'm happy to improve my old content, even if I am no longer writing new answers.

Answer (score -4):

This is ridiculous. If I refer to a user as "he", but the user is actually a "she", and said user becomes offended, that is the user making nothing into an issue.

When a gender is not known, it is perfectly normal to say "he". This is common in human language. It is human nature.

Personally, I sometimes refer to users as he/she. I think this is more than fair.

Comment: It is "ridiculous" if you think this discussion is exclusively about language. But making computing a space where women are made to feel welcome, and are encouraged to be part of the programmer community from an age young enough to make a difference, is hardly ridiculous.

Comment: (@SList, you need to use people's handle if you wish to address them directly. Alvin will see a notification from your message, but you need to use my handle if you want to ping me.)

Comment: @SList, as to your comment, I am more than happy to hear your thoughts as to _why_ you believe no problem exists at all (that sounds to be your position). I'm a male programmer and a feminist, and whilst I wish that were fashionable, that does not accord with my experience! Do you believe that the wide gender disparity in computing (assuming we agree on that) is just evidence that women are broadly not interested in it? How about engineering, the physical sciences, politics? Genuinely interested in your view, if you wish to put it forward.

Comment: (@SList, a reminder about using handles again. I'll reply to your thoughts in due course).

Comment: @SList, I can't imagine any feminist interested in rebalancing tech gender who would advocate "making it more pink". In fact, if I saw such a thing, I think I'd call them out on their sexism. The purpose of such programmes is to try to reverse the subtle societal mechanisms that act as a gender filter early in the career choice process. Your view seems to be that most (girly, pink-loving?) women are unsuited to programming, which seems a strange position for a female programmer to take. Do you believe that lack of aptitude accounts for all/most of the gender imbalance?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there is any intention to guide people towards careers to which they are ill-suited. The intellectual basis of challenging gender norms in computing (and in other fields too) is that (some/more) women have a great deal to offer, and that it would be a pity if they were to lose out based on long-standing discrimination. Thus, it is about people (and teams) fulfilling more of their potential.

Comment: @SList, I am finding it hard to understand your world-view. Paraphrased, it is: there's absolutely zero gender discrimination of female computer engineers. The wide gender inequality in tech is down purely to competence, brain wiring, education, training and lack of interest - pretty much every factor but discrimination! However, you are quite sure that discrimination _does_ exist in banking, though you don't explain why this is different. That this topic (here and elsewhere) generates so much interest is unimportant, because any (female) perception of discrimination is just imaginary.

Comment: @SList, not putting words into your mouth at all - the use of paraphrasing is quite a normal technique to "join the dots" - if I get part of my summary wrong, you have the full opportunity to correct it. I fear that your sweeping view of "all liberals" and how dreadful you perceive them to be has brought you to the view that "there's no problem here, move along".

Comment: Additionally, there are a few women on this very page who don't seem to agree, and [plenty more on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=female+computer+engineer+sexism). I don't want to invalidate your view, but I wonder if you are extrapolating from your experience (of having seen little or no gender discrimination) and finding that to be the case for every female in tech? The folks [who wrote this](http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/Male_Programmer_Privilege_Checklist) seem to have seen/experienced it. I mean the question in earnest: is it all in their head also?

Comment: Ha, well if you find a group "bigotted, extremist, inflexible, dogmatic" then I suspect "dreadful" is a perfectly apt shorthand for your view! But that's semantics, and we should not dwell on it. I don't believe I've deleted a link - maybe I just transferred it to a later comment, finding it would not fit? Anyway, I am minded to leave the discussion, since you seem to find me arguing without good faith (please note that disagreeing with you is not the same as failing to permit you to have a view). Thanks for the exchange though, it is good to read opposing viewpoints.

Answer (score -10):

It's not the problem with the language, that forces to distinguish between male and female. It's the problem with the distinguishing language + the environment, that makes that distinction hard or impossible. The languages has evolved in the environment where you always known who are you talking with. Don't blame the language for the problems you create. Don't blame people for creating problems, too, because it's just like the intelligence is working - creating problems that hasn't existed before and learning how to cope with it.

The answer suggesting that the gender should be displayed was heavily downvoted. I can't understand it, I agree with Tim's comment:

> programmers function best when dealing with defined rules that they
>   either break, or don't break

Many people are unwilling to put it clear, how they want to be addressed (as male or female) and then have problems when someone hasn't guessed correctly. It's a bit paranoia from my point of view. You can't blame people for not knowing what you're not willing to tell.

Some people suggest modifying English language to make it 'gender-neutral' like (according to my knowledge) Chinese. Why not make it easier to switch to Chinese, than? Problem solved! Forcing people to use the 'modified' version of the language is similar to forcing them to learn a new language. Many people make a lot effort to learn English, and instead of appreciation they meet blames that they don't use grammar forms they were learned to be invalid.

The best solution, in my opinion, would be to add **voluntary** gender icon near the nickname. But it's not likely to be implemented, so just **don't spill milk over it**. You can hate English or you can love it, but it's the English site and you should just live with it.

Comment: There is nothing forcing you to use a gender pronoun unless you're referring to something that is attributed to a specific gender. As many answers have already shown, one can easily write text without gender pronouns. And there is very little content on SO that is gender specific.

Answer (score -14):

How about another take on all this. Why don't we just put a Male or Female choice for SO profiles? And have them display next to the name.

Like the arrow one for male and Egyptian cross looking thing for female? That way there's much more transparency and everyone can easily respect each other.

It's so much nicer to refer to someone as [he] or [she] AND get it right ... isn't it?

Comment: This opens up a whole other can of worms if the choice is required, and if it's optional, most people won't use it.

Comment: Well that's the point. You make it optional, and if the people take advantage of it then it will solve it. If they don't, no problem :).

Comment: Not no problem: we have to spend time building support for it.  And we don't wanna.  Besides: the gender selector, if one wants to make it plain, is your avatar.

Comment: @BenCollins Can you please elaborate on spending time to build support for it? What are you referring to here exactly (code development?) ? The Avatar thing is not really what my idea is about.

Comment: Such optional fields cause preferentials trends to emerge and create negative impact on the site. For example, "location" is an optional field, and recently, [there seems to be a trend emerging](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262150/2982225) due to this _optional field_.

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly. A lot of women don't want to openly display their gender on sites like SO (because - let's face it - sexual harrassment is a fact, esp. in male-dominated industries like IT). If someone chooses to keep as much anonymity as possible, this is no excuse for treating them with less respect than others who are more open in this regard, and consistently using the wrong pronoun when addressing someone is quite disrespectful IMHO.

Comment: I strongly agree with @FrankSchmitt. By the time I started using on-line forums, in the early 1980's, I was over 30, well established in my career, and effectively harassment-proof, so I didn't have to conceal my gender. That may not be the case for much younger women and girls.

Comment: ".. the arrow one for male and Egyptian cross looking thing for female .." – those are not Egyptian but – strange but true – astronomy symbols for *planets*: one indicates Mars, the other is Venus. Brownie points for guessing which one is which.

Comment: For me, one of the nice things about being a programmer online is that I am exactly that, a programmer, not a female programmer.  Putting my gender on my profile takes that away from me.  That doesn't mean I am ok being thought of as a male and referred to as "he", it means I don't want to be thought of as either.

Answer (score -32):

How about SO allows users to specify their gender and displays their username in an appropriate colour? Would solve the problem for those that care and could be ignored by those that don't (no choice made - display in green...)

Comment: At least I would be a "don't care", as I really do not see how my gender would change the questions or answers, this ain't no date site. Maybe it would be more useful to add a "he/she/they" choice?

Comment: Hum... Let me think of a cliché: blue for boys and pink for girls?

Comment: @Bruno: Well, a snippet from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink "In 19th century England, pink ribbons or decorations were often worn by young boys; boys were simply considered small men, and while men in England wore red uniforms, boys wore pink." Similar things have happened with blue, it has not necessarily been very manly color ("Virgin Mary in blue"). So, the cliché is actually less clichée than one would think...

Comment: Not sure why this was so heavily down-voted, programmers function best when dealing with defined rules that they either break, or don't break. "I'd rather not think about that, I'd like to talk about C instead if you don't mind" isn't an abnormal mindset. Take a moment and think before voting, while we would certainly not do this for a plethora of reasons, it's not like this is a feature request.

Comment: How would we choose the gender-indicative colors?

Comment: @TimPost: This being meta, people are downvoting because they disagree. You apparently also disagree ("[...] we would certainly not do this for a plethora of reasons [...]"), so I'm not sure why you feel they shouldn't be downvoting.

Comment: @TimPost I think part of the downvotes are for using color to indicate gender, not for indicating gender in general.

Comment: @Timpost With regard to the "off at a tangent" comment (now deleted) - The subtext that our dumbed-down community can't grasp is "It works both ways;Rules can be used and abused." If there was a similar site which targeted traditionally-female areas, would the same presumption of gender be applied in reverse? Would a male be regarded as precious for protesting? Apparently, the minority of the minority that chooses to take offence insists we waste time formulating responses to suit their preferences.

Comment: The twitter-escapees have mindlessly and mechanically downvoted my suggestion. They apparently learned nothing from the arena scene where Loretta's perpetual irrelevant interjections completely disrupted Reg's policy development. Brainless naysaying takes neither talent nor effort. I've suggested that those who are concerned may choose to colour-code themselves. So - the problem is colour? What alternative means have these geniuses suggested? I'm out of here before the mob finds its pitchforks.

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit sarcastic in an earlier comment, but more seriously, you will never get all male users to agree on their colour and all female users to agree on theirs. The compromise would certainly have to be dictated by the typical conventions you find in baby toys stores and all that. Either way, this sounds like a terrible prospect for all parties involved.