# What does a greyed-out answer mean?

Tags: support, answers, user-interface

I was under the impression that it meant that the answerer deleted his post. But today, I was able to comment on that answer which is leading me to believe that my assumption was wrong.

> [image: Greyed-out answer]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answers with a score of -3 (-8 on meta) or lower are automatically greyed out.

A greyed out answer does not mean that it's deleted, because deleted answers get a reddish background (and you can only see deleted answers if you are the author, a moderator, or have 10k rep or more).

Comment: Right, wasn't aware of the auto-greying by the system.

Comment: @ProgramFOX am I right in thinking meta has a different threshold? (if so, do you know what it is?) or is just that I've usually been reading for a long time by the time I reach the lowest voted answers on meta and the downvotes came in after page load?

Comment: @OGHaza Yes, you are right about that. I saw a -5 post here that was not greyed out. I don't know the threshold, unfortunately.

Comment: @OGHaza & ProgramFox: Threshold on Meta is -8 and below ([-7 post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262119/the-use-of-gender-specific-pronouns-on-stack-overflow/262229#262229), [-8 post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/251864#251864)).

Comment: I second that impression of the question being deleted!

Comment: Why make it bleak at all, as if the reader cannot read the number for votes?