# Show ignored questions on hover

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, ignored-tags

I think that it is a good idea to grey out questions with ignored tags, as currently happens:
[image] However, I think that these questions should go back to full colour as you hover on them, as happens with [answers of -3 or less](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262423/what-does-a-greyed-out-answer-mean). (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138600/initializing-a-static-stdmapint-int-in-c/24584993#24584993) for an answer of <-3)
This would be a useful feature for me, because it would allow me to view them easily if I wanted to. I realise that the purpose of 'Ignored Tags' is tags that you want to ignore, but I frequently use them to remove from my notice questions I won't be able to answer, even if they may be helpful to me for solving my own problems.
Unless there is some reason that people would find this annoying or in anyway negative, please could we implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally find this very irritating.

Even though I seldom look at question tags these days, when I *do*, having those questions which are ignored appear lesser is a huge plus for me since I'm not as tempted to click any link-looking thing about it.

If it highlighted into view, that would indicate that I should give it more attention than I want to, since I was the one who made the determination to ignore them in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough, I do not think I would feel this but there we go. I was trying to find the question that discussed the introduction of full cover on hover for <-2 answers, but failed. I think it discussed extra attention being drawn by the change in colour aswell.