# Editing out gender pronouns in answers

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, gender

There's been [discussion about gendered pronouns and answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262119/the-use-of-gender-specific-pronouns-on-stack-overflow), I'm interested in whether replacing an unsupported gendered pronoun is sufficient justification for making an edit to an answer.

I came across an answer recently, to an question asked by a user with no gender indicated in their profile that begin "He asked for [blah] so ...".

In cases such as this where the user's gender is unstated, should we actively moderate implicit gender assumptions (replacing with the Username, 'they', etc as appropriate)? Many posts in the coming months are going to be by CS101 students, it's a shame to address those of non-male gender identity as male by default, reinforcing the idea they don't belong.

Comment: No, you should never edit because of small details like this, especially not in the case of answers. If it really bothers you, feel free to leave a comment asking the poster to rephrase his answer.

Comment: If you're editing other things in the post, I can't say I'd really care if you changed those pronouns. But if that's the only edit you're making, absolutely not - even if there's nothing else to edit in the post, that's still too minor.

Comment: And just so you know, @dabhaid, voting on Meta [meta-tag:discussion] questions indicates agreement or disagreement. The plethora of downvotes on your question are not indicating that this is a bad question, but rather that they think the answer is "no".

Answer (score 51):

No, you should not actively edit out those pronouns.

The key thing to ask yourself before editing is: *does my edit improve the question/answer in a measurable way?*

There is nothing personal intended when someone refers to someone else as 'he'/'him' on this site. If someone leaves an obvious clue as to their gender then people can properly use the appropriate pronoun. But if they don't leave a clue then they have no right complaining that their feelings have been hurt or they're offended due to incorrect gender reference.

Comment: I don't expect anyone will have their feelings hurt by the assumption, my concern is more that it reinforces the idea that coders are supposed to be men. That it's 'nothing personal' is exactly the point - nothing is meant by it, but it's exclusionary _and_ accepted.

Comment: @dabhaid Nobody ever said coders were *supposed* to be men, I'm not sure where you got that notion from. Most reasonable people know that coding is like some other professions (i.e. nursing, firefighting) that are predominantly - but not exclusively - populated by one gender. That's just the way it is - don't be imagining problems where none exist.

Comment: Maybe we should start referring to everyone who doesn't leave a clue about their gender as "she" and see how that goes over.

Comment: It works in the legal field.

Comment: I'd find it weird that someone asking a question finishes with: "By the way, I'm a girl". I think profiles should have an optional gender field. Most people wouldn't care at all to make it public, I'm assuming.

Comment: The default way of referring to people in a general way should be gender-neutral until the person has specified their pronoun. Using he/him as the generic catch-all is not, and never has been, gender-neutral.

Comment: @Dici You can put that information in your profile bio and users will see it when they hover over your user card, which is visible and hoverable for all posts authored by you.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow many things have changed on this site since I wrote that answer. In general I agree with you, but using him/he was the way it was done back then. A [previously linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266104/109702) summarises things nicely. But now we make every attempt to use the right pronouns *if they are known* rather than using a catch-all. BTW, the pronoun thing works both ways - I felt weirded out when referred to as "them" not long ago, even though that is now the (company preferred) standard.

Answer (score 15):

I'm sympathetic to the idea of fixing gender-specific pronouns, and I agree with your comment that this mode of address may act in subtle/subconscious exclusionary ways. At any rate, English seems to be moving away from the idea that an assumption of 'he' is gender non-specific, and writing style guides are endorsing 'they' as a singular alternative, so one could argue for the more modern form anyway.

However, there's a balance to be struck. We could end up with enthusiastic editors changing this wording on its own, which would push a lot of old content to the front page, reducing the sites' usefulness and annoying everyone. By all means, if you see other things wrong with a post (all upper/lower-case, excessive emboldening/italics, lack of paragraphing, poor spelling, txtspk) then you could change this at the same time if you wish.

Just be aware that, whilst most people won't mind, some people will strenuously object, and their counter-reaction may result in damage to the original cause. Thus, it is probably wise to tread carefully. Unfortunately, gender equality and the principles of political correctness *are* politically polarised, and we cannot require people to endorse them prior to using the site.

I will occasionally edit out instances of 'lame' (i.e. disabled) and 'retarded' (i.e. learning difficulties, [see here](http://www.r-word.org/)) for much the same reasons, but I don't go on edit hunts. That seems to strike the right balance, between shaping Stack Overflow to be welcoming place for everyone whilst not censoring *every* lazy use of inappropriate language.