# Please add pronouns to profiles

Tags: feature-request

Other apps (Zoom, Slack, LinkedIn, Facebook, Instagram) have created an optional pronouns field in their profile editing tools.

Pronouns do not tell the reader about the person's gender or sexual orientation, they just make it clear how the person would like to be referred to in the third person.

Adding your pronouns shows support for the practice of asking for pronouns rather than assuming them based on name or appearance, and helps gain acceptance for the trans and nonbinary community. It's important for trans and nonbinary people to be able to share pronouns.

Please add a pronouns field to the profile page on Stack Exchange, make it optional, allow people to enter whatever pronouns they want, and have the option of displaying them on the card that pops up when you hover over a person's name on questions and answers.

I am aware that they can be added in the free text profile, status, etc, but I prefer it when apps add a specific field for this (as Instagram and Facebook have done), so it doesn't use up the word-count and it prompts everyone to add it. If you don't want to add your pronouns, it would be optional anyway.

Comment: If you want to display your pronouns, put them at the top of your about me, that'll already show them in your user card. There's no need to add specific functionality for this.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265436

Comment: @Nick isn't that done through a userscript? Not a feature i've ever seen "that'll already show them in your user card."

Comment: Ah, the hover popup. that'd explain why i never see it, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "it prompts everyone to add it." this is an advantage? Also, I don't know what the character limit is, but I've seen really long bios. It's not like twitter, where the bio is so short (and also people on twitter show their pronouns a lot).

Comment: Yes, it is an advantage for those whose pronouns are not the default if everyone adds a pronoun

Comment: Orthogonally, while it is apparent you do care about people, this is a discussion that has been had a lot over the past years. The official stance of SO is to use pronouns when they are added to the bio. Many people from the lavender that I've seen interact with the posts on meta.se about that topic seemed to find it sufficient. May I inquire as to why it doesn't suffice for you, if it did for them?

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I looked at the other discussions, and they were a posted a long while ago, and were asking about adding gender to profiles rather than adding pronouns, which is a different request.

Comment: No Yvonne, there were specifically immense amounts of discussions on meta.shackexchange.com about *pronouns*, specifically. I can try and round them up if you really want, but please try and see that maybe it really happened.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier I searched for "pronouns" and "pronouns in profile" and got a lot of posts about gender. Please feel free to flag this as a possible duplicate if you believe this exact same question has been asked before.

Comment: You might want to read up on the Monica Cellio clusterfuck. She was a moderator that's been removed from the site in the aftermaths of SE enforcing the use of user's pronouns, mainly over misunderstandings, from what the public has been told. Again, I'm not only talking about meta.stackoverflow but about meta.**stackexchange**, the mother site.

Comment: What I mean is thanks for your efforts, but we're really quite aware of the needs, influences and help that pronouns can add to the discussion, and currently it feels a bit like you seem to think nobody else is aware of the problem space. We are, have put a lot of thought and internet ink over it, and found a solution where the *actual people concerned* seemed to agree.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier my pronoun is they, that's why I am asking. I am one of the actual people concerned.

Comment: Also, I fail to see why some people are so vehemently opposed to a proposed **optional** feature.

Comment: Because, as Dharman has aptly put it, it diverts from the idea of the site. This isn't a dating app, nor a social media place. Also, please read Taco's answer, especially the quote from Adam Lear and related posts, it's very aptly explained why one could be opposed to it.

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like a feature that would mostly be used to tell up on people would wouldn't fill up said *optional* field. It's already the case on many other sites, such as twitter, where the absence of pronouns in a bio is brought up as a reason to believe someone to be an asshole. Like, the spirit of the idea is cool, but in reality I really do not think it shares awareness, helps communication or appease people. It mostly puts emphasis on something that has great potential for creating holier-than-thou wars.

Comment: There are all sorts of reasons for not putting your pronoun in your profile; it doesn't necessarily mean that the person is being an a$$hole

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236978/discussion-between-felix-adriyel-gagnon-grenier-and-yvonne-aburrow).

Comment: Similar proposal at MSE: *[Pronoun-specific field in profile (that also shows up in hovercard)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369729/)*

Comment: Also see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335078/369403), there already is a sort-of standardized place to put pronouns and a userscript that will display them, if you somehow happen to use pronouns to refer to a specific user on Stack Overflow (outside of chat, it happens very rarely for me, and people that do often misuse comments).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm honestly not *for* the idea's implementation.

---

While I believe we should show support for the LGTBQ+ community, I don't believe it should be done as part of a new feature. There are already features that would allow us to do exactly what you're asking.

#### Show it at the top of your about section:

You can already add it to your about section. Simply add emphasis to it by making it a header (using the pound symbol `#`):

[image: Screenshot of my about me.]

#### Show it in your summary:

Using the `summary` tag, you can change what information is displayed when others hover over your profile picture on the site:

[image: Screenshot of my summary tag.]

The syntax for this is:

```
<!-- summary: Oh, umm, hello there.  (She/Her) -->
```

---

Additionally, Stack Exchange sites tend to focus on the content rather than the authors. I believe this is a good approach, as summarized in [Adam Lear's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266104/9893154):

> I'm gonna go with echoing the other answers: we try as much as possible to divert attention away from who is posting and channel it towards what the post is.

Comment: That's a really cool trick with the `summary: ` syntax, I didn't know that existed!

Comment: Pound symbol? When did it start supporting Markdown? It used to be HTML only.

Answer (score 43):

### No!

A user is a user. There's no need for pronouns. When you address my user, use my nickname or "you". When you talk about my user, use "they".

Stack Overflow is not about users. It is about content. There's no need to know each others' pronouns because that is an irrelevant detail.

If you really must share this personal information on Stack Overflow then use the "About me" section on your profile. That is the only place where personal information is allowed.

Comment: Fine as long as people actually do default to they when someone's gender is unknown, not so good when people default to he.

Comment: It is probably out of the scope of the website, as I noticed there is not even direct chat messages, we can refer to questions or answers rather than users

Comment: Sometimes when you add a comment referring to someone else's answer, you need to refer to them in the third person in the course of the comment.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow You can use their username. That's what it's for.

Comment: Example: " @Dharman replied to my comment. Then Dharman replied to my comment again." Wouldn't it be more natural to use a 3rd person pronoun the second time I mention you in that example?

Comment: @YvonneAburrow "@Dharman replied to my comment. Then **_they_** replied to my comment again".

Comment: @YvonneAburrow what makes you compelled to specify their gender, though? Is it related to the conversation? No, I doubt it. Is English not suited for gender-neutral speech? No, it is extremely well-suited for that - you can read a whole book and not know what gender characters in it are. So, the question is - why can't we all live happily ever after with neutral language (as long as it is not forced down our throats as it tends trigger negative response)?

Comment: Yes I think it would be great if everyone defaulted to **they** @10Rep

Comment: Gender neutral is fine with me @OlegValter - it is just that a lot of people still default to "he"

Comment: @YvonneAburrow ah, well, then I highly doubt new fields will help, sorry, but I really do - it's hard to get people to sign up to any particular speech type. Not to mention that many come from languages that simply lack gender-neutral constructs, so it feels natural to them to default to whatever they associate themselves with (or what gender the word "user" is). My language is one such, for example. Not to mention that we've been a predominantly male industry for quite a while - this will all go away with time as representation improves, no need to force it.

Comment: @OlegValter I think this one of those chicken-and-egg issues: raising the profile of female and nonbinary developers might help to improve representation; but the problem will also go away as representation improves.

Comment: artificially inflating the "profile" of a minority group only grows resentment against them. It's relatively common to force the issue now days and simply sweep opposition "under the rug," so to speak, rather than working toward a more inclusive goal. The current state of affairs is if you see content that would be better written in a gender neutral format, it's 100% acceptable to suggest an edit making that change and there's a very high chance that it will be approved. there's no need to instead go to the comments and start a discussion about it on SO. Edit, and go next

Comment: @YvonneAburrow that's exactly what I've been trying to put across :) It does not help the cause as we *already* have an explicit endorsement for putting pronouns in profiles should one want to and no restrictions whatsoever on what profile "about me" can contain. Social change starts with campaigning for non-discriminatory job opportunity practices, on abolishment of restrictions on what professions are restricted to males only (did you know that in Russia we still have a list of jobs where women *cannot* work even if they want to?), etc. Not in these gestures - this is my firm belief.

Comment: Can't you just apply an avatar which contains your preferred pronouns as a stack of words? I mean, I'm not defined as a programmer or volunteer by my gender, so I am not personally interested.  But for those who put a high priority on the world knowing their preferred pronouns, you can ensure that everyone sees it on every post by declaring in your avatar.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow How will adding pronouns have impact on representation of any group? Also why representation matters? When it comes to professionals, it does not matter who you are, it matters whether you are good developer or not, and that you are not complete jerk to others. To do your job you are using a brain, not other parts of your body, so representation does not mean a thing. Bringing it up only makes things worse, because it enforces idiotic beliefs they are here to tick some diversity mark, instead being judged by their expertise.

Answer (score 31):

> Other apps (Zoom, Slack, LinkedIn, Facebook, Instagram)

What is common to all examples you listed is they are *social networks* and *communication tools*. They are all about interactions between users, that's their primary goal, and, as such, having features enabling users to *explicitly* state their preferred pronouns makes some sense.

Stack Overflow is not a social network. Nor is it a communication tool. It is a *questions and answers* site. The most amount of interaction users have is here, on Meta (which is more like a [Greek agora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agora) than a social club), and in chat, and that is it.

> it prompts everyone to add it

If one feels strongly about specifying one's preferred pronouns, they *will* add this information to the profile. If someone does not feel this way, they will not *regardless* of being prompted or not. This is included in the definition of caring about something: you either care or you do not.

It will not make anyone *more* inclined to specify their pronouns (see above) than they already were. It will also not dissuade anyone who does not want to respect pronouns from disregarding them. In the end, the existence of this will lead to one more field a user has to fill out (or ignore) when signing up or editing their profile. A token and empty gesture.

> so it doesn't use up the word-count

Not to mention that the `AboutMe` column in the `Users` table has the data type of `nvarchar(max)` ([learn more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) about SEDE) which means one can add [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11131977/11407695) of information about them there. I am pretty sure those who care about pronouns can find some space to fit a statement in.

Comment: "It will not make anyone more inclined to specify their pronouns (see above) than they already were."

I do not currently have my pronouns in my profile but I would add them if it generally felt safer to do so. Having a field for it makes it feel more generally accepted. I guess the only way to test either hypothesis would be to add the field experimentally.

Comment: Again, on a social network, such as those you have listed, the focus is on the person. On this site, however, the focus is on the content, not the person, for example, when one votes on a question, they should base their vote on question quality and appropriateness alone, and not allow questioner ranking, seniority or experience to play into how their question is rated, and this site succeeds in its nitch partly because of this. I vote that we continue to focus on content and leave pronouns to dating apps.

Comment: It is more than a pure questions-and-answers site. It is very much an *ego-driven* questions- and-answers site (for instance, Wikipedia is not ego-driven) and thus it *is* to some extent also about users. The ego-driven part is by design.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow You say "I would add them if it generally felt safer to do so" Why do you feel it is unsafe to put them in your bio? Or what do you think it would happen if you put them now, comparing to having specific field?

Comment: @PeterMortensen did I mention anywhere it is a *pure* Q&A site? :) On an off-note, I am also a proponent of making user cards much less visible on posts or even removed completely.

Answer (score 18):

You know, I'm a human being. The times have changed a lot and in a very short time period; faster than I myself am capable to process. The world around me frustrates me, a lot. The gender discussion especially makes me feel alien. Ironic, but true.

Stack Overflow's way of dealing with people has always been: don't deal with people. Deal with content only. Hence it is a common consensus to refer to each other through our surrogates - the user account. If the username is not applicable then use "you", "them", "they". Wonderful words. Simple. Impossible to confuse. And then here comes a feature request which is designed to throw all that to the wind and basically *change* a core tenant of Stack Overflow. You might say "no it's just an input field" - it never is. It sets an example, one where gender all of a sudden is seen as important enough to give a dedicated input field for it. You should not be surprised it gets such a strong resistance.

Stack Overflow actually has *not* changed in all this time - something I very much like. I want Stack Overflow to stay like it is: simple to understand, rule-based, all about the content, not about the users, no fuss. Everyone needs stable pillars in their life, Stack Overflow is one for me. And I believe I am in very good company there.

If you can't cope with the fact that Stack Overflow does not bend like social media does and stays as rigid and impersonal as ever... this might not be a site you can participate in. If it does change, then it will no longer be a site I can participate in.