# Was my answer inappropriate or should the user be flagged?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderation

An [unclear question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676001/how-to-store-google-places-in-2-edittexts/) has been asked by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7904911/jaiit-betul) on 28-04-2017. I have flagged his question after he started being unprofessional and clearly incoherent.

Can we have some moderation attention regarding this? Or was my behavior inappropriate?

Comment: You can flag it as rude, as I just did

Comment: Question has been deleted by user...

Comment: Side note: you may also consider flagging your own comment "More than you think. But we are overflowed with people who don't read the rules ." as "rude and offensive" and this post the same way for "clearly incoherent"... I'd say yes, your behavior is inappropriate (irrespective whether the other person's behavior). You also may want to check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262119/the-use-of-gender-specific-pronouns-on-stack-overflow on your usage of "he/him".

Answer (score 6):

If you think that the question isn't clear *you shouldn't have answered it*.  You should only be answering clear questions where an answer can unambiguously be determined.  If the question isn't clear *vote to close it as being unclear*, and if you would like to, comment to try to help the OP clarify the question.