# I find it sad that moderator nominations are focused on flagging and closing

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I don't know about you, but when I went through the moderator election page, I noticed that some of the candidates were focusing on the fact that they're very active with their flags and close votes.

Although that's good when you need law enforcers to keep the place clean, especially considering how Stack Overflow is a victim of its own success and gets a dozen (bad quality) new questions per second, I find that... I don't know, awkward?

It's a good thing to let the new people know that they should think twice before posting their question. But should Stack Overflow really be a synonym for "retribution"?

Comment: Retribution? As long as you see moderation as punitive, yeah your viewpoint of Stack will be sad. Once you shift your perspective to understand Stack's goals and how it wants to achieve them, moderation becomes the nicest and most benevolent thing you can do.

Comment: @Patrice I think I used the wrong word there. I didn't mean to say that moderation in its own is punitive, but the fact that I was under the impression some candidates promise to apply it more fiercely. Then again, that's only my impression, and I can be wrong.

Comment: Could you please clarify your suggestion? You seem to think moderator *should not* know when flagging is appropriate and *should not* know when closing question is appropriate (as you find "fact that they're very active on the flags and close votes" wrong/sad/whatever) - I don't see how such person would be good moderator.

Comment: Well if moderation isn't punitive.... Why is more of it a bad thing?

Comment: The whole *point* of moderation is to keep the site clean.  Moderators are empowered to do that with abilities more powerful than regular users.  Focusing on flags and close votes is going to be some of the most important work they can do as a moderator.

Comment: @Patrice Hmm... I think I'm not judging moderation on its own, but giving my point of view on the way some people were proposing themselves.

Comment: It's important to note that the purpose of closing legitimate questions isn't to send the question asker away.  If a question is being closed because it's a dupe, closing is giving the asker an answer.  If a question is being closed because it can't be answered in its current state, it's giving the asker a clear message about what they need to add to get their question answered.  And if a question is spam, well, we all want it removed as quickly as possible anyway.  Moderation is by-and-large a process of delivering better answers faster.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler I gotta admit, I forgot that bit for a moment there.

Comment: @fbueckert Agreed. But I was thinking being slightly more... "diplomat" would be a better approach? As in, talk it out beforehand? Then again, I think I'm being too idealistic.

Comment: Talk it out?  With the two thousand new posters we get each and every day?  Where is anyone supposed to find the *time* to do that?  Never mind that new user have to be receptive and *willing* to learn.  Most of them don't care; they just want an answer, and anything that prevents that is to be worked around.

Comment: @fbueckert Yeah, guess I tend to forget that SO is a lot more viral than the other SE websites, to the point of being uncontrollable.

Comment: What do you think the candidates _should_ focus on? Dealing with flags what moderators _do_.

Comment: I mean, you are more than welcome to do the 'hand holding' and all. Most of the regulars do.... Sometimes. But with the flood there is just no time to do it 100% of the time. Also since mods are expected to handle flags like crazy.... Why doesn't it make sense to say they already flag well?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Carefully choosing my words there. From my point of view, a mix of "both". Let the people know that, if you stumble on an "OP" author who's... showing promises, then you're going to treat him slightly more indulgently (doesn't mean you can't close the question until they edit it back into something acceptable though).

Comment: @Clockwork Are you suggesting that moderators should vary rules of the site based on they own preferences? (or maybe I don't get what you mean "treat … more indulgently") Can you provide an example how valid NAA flag would be handled "more indulgently" for example?

Comment: @Clockwork side note: check out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262119/the-use-of-gender-specific-pronouns-on-stack-overflow/262129 (not directly related to your post, but somewhat related to style of comments)

Comment: You find it sad that moderator candidates are focused on... *moderating*? What exactly do you think the candidates should be focused on? What, to you, is moderation on Stack Overflow? What does it consist of? What do moderators do?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov By now, I know that my point of view was based off the wrong idea, but I was just trying to give my point of view on moderation candidacy (and not moderation by itself). I was thinking that, as a possible future moderator, you'd try to reflect the community by showing that you're a nice folk (but that doesn't mean you can't handle flags the way it's already done).

Comment: @CodyGray I tried to @ you on my above comment too, but it told me I was trying to notify the "OP" author (which is me I guess?) for some reasons.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks a lot for the link by the way. I usually do my best to remain gender neutral, but I think I was tired yesterday night and forgot to maintain it. That, and the fact that gender neutral pronoun doesn't exist in my mother tongue didn't help.

Comment: You can only ping one person per comment. You can't elect based on being "nice folk". All the candidates seem like nice folks. How would you pick? And how does that qualify you to do the actual work of moderating? The relation of moderators to "nice" is two-fold: (1) we keep the engagement on this site nice by cleaning up abusive comments and/or enforcing the rules when users break them, and (2) we keep the site itself nice by removing clutter/garbage/low-quality content. Some people consider closure and deletion to be "not nice", but that is a misunderstanding. Quality is why we're all here.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I think I got that now, after all the exchanges I've had, and Machavity's answer (and link).

Comment: @one who have less than 2000k rep can easily have thousands of flag (thanks to flag for closing question) but after that it is really hard to find post worthy of flag so elect on the basis of flags only! - NO (imho) but closing is more appropriate

Comment: @NullPoiиteя There are many specialized areas of flagging. Some people easily fill their 100 flags a day by flagging bad or obsolete comments, NAA (not an answer) posts, serial voting, plagiarism, etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you're mistaken about what moderators **do** on SO.

> But should Stack Overflow really be a synonym for "retribution"?

Retribution isn't it. *At all.* Mostly moderators are dealing with those special queues that involve both user and system flags. A lot of flags. So if someone runs for moderator, you probably want someone who already helps handling some general moderator duties. Some people don't get that and act like it's a popularity contest, or some sort of rite of passage.

You also need to get that moderators are the top of the [curation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367016/curation-and-cynicism-or-why-stack-overflow-sometimes-doesnt-seem-welcoming) food chain. That means they're on the lookout for bad things to remove (like spam, rudeness, etc.) and dealing with the occasional problem user. If you're a good flagger, you're going to be a better moderator.

Honestly, posts like these make it harder on moderation in general. Too many people see SO as an angry place, but if you hang around and do moderation, you find it's nothing of the sort.

Comment: Thanks. With all the exchanges I've had, and with your answer, I think I've got the discussion I was looking for. I was on a thoughtful night and seeking various people point of view.

Comment: As a side note, I also wanted to point out that I didn't mean anything toward those who are contributing to moderating SO. I've been there for a short while, so I know how much of a hell it can be to keep stuffs clean around. I was just thinking about having a discussion about the candidacy. Maybe I should have taken a trip to the chat instead of opening a thread though.

Comment: *"Too many people see SO as an angry place"* - while in fact it's pretty much Willy Wonka's chocolate factory.